# Best way to solve imports of file in same package but in different directory with Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to **clean** my code structure and put class/object files in another directories in my gatling project.

If i put all simulation class and utils class in the same directory and same package i do not need an import statement and everything works fine.

Let's say my structure is as follow :

```
/user-files
----/simulations
--------MySimulation.scala
----/utils
--------Router.scala
```

I have tried several import or naming configuration to be able to use Router in my Simulation.

1. Follow package naming as directories structure
2. Put simulations and utils class in the same package

I have also tried different style of import

```
//using package
import packagename.Router

//another try
import packagename.Router._

//without package name
import Router._
```

My attempt to search a solution on scala docs or stack overflow didn't helped me.

This is the error given after executing gatling.bat

```
not found: value Router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that this way: there's one single source folder, which is by default `/user-files/simulations`.

If you want to use folders/packages (which is a good thing), you can have a structure such as:

```
/user-files
----/simulations
--------MySimulation.scala
--------/utils
------------Router.scala
```

Then, in Scala, packages and folder hierarchy are not related, BUT it's a good practice to use the same convention as in Java.

So, you would have:

```
package utils
object Router
```

then in MySimulation:

```
import utils.Router
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stephane. Do you know why one single source folder is forced ? I have also searched in Gatling docs but it seems not mentioned.

Comment: That's just how it works. We try to keep things simple.